# Why is the array using numpy.reshape not being stored properly?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's consider an n-by-m array of values that I want to reshape into `n*m-by-1` array for storage and plotting. The n-by-m array is the result of some analyses that takes place in a for loop that gets written over each iteration.

Each time I construct the `n*m-by-1` array, I want to store the stacked columns into a separate variable and then increment the column number so I eventually end up with an array that is `n*m-by-k` where k is how many separate Excel files I'm working with.

The code below will replicate the error and illustrate the point.

```
import numpy as np

number = [2,4]

new_a = np.zeros((3,6))
vec_for_plot = np.zeros((3,6))

a = np.random.random((3,6))

i = 0

for n in range(0,len(number)):
    new_a = a + number[n]
    vec_for_plot = np.reshape(new_a,(-1,1))
    i = i + 1
```

If I try to assemble the `n*m-by-1` array into the `vec_for_plot` variable using:

`vec_for_plot[:,i] = np.reshape(new_a,(-1,1))`

then the following error shows up.

`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (18,1) into shape (18)`

I've tried np.column_stack, switching the indices, initializing empty matrices, matrices of zeros, etc.

Can someone please provide some guidance on where my indexing is going wrong?

Comment: When I run the main block you pasted, everything goes fine. After I run that last line, I get a different error: `IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1`. Are you sure this is the code you ran?

Comment: `vec_for_plot[:,i] = np.reshape(new_a,(-1))` or `vec_for_plot[:,i] = new_a.ravel()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [40]: arr = np.zeros((3,6))
```

When I index a 'column' of this array, I get a 1d array, shape (3,):

```
In [41]: arr[:,0]                 
Out[41]: array([0., 0., 0.])
In [42]: _.shape
Out[42]: (3,)
```

I can assign another (3,) shape array to it:

```
In [43]: arr[:,0] = np.arange(3)
In [44]: arr
Out[44]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I can also assign a (1,3) shaped array:

```
In [45]: arr[:,1] = np.ones((1,3))
In [46]: arr
Out[46]: 
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

But I cannot assign a (3,1) shape.  That's what you are trying to do:

```
In [47]: arr[:,1] = np.ones((3,1))*2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-47-d7829ffd8ee7>", line 1, in <module>
    arr[:,1] = np.ones((3,1))*2
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3,)
```

This is a variant on the basic `broadcasting` rules.  When adding a (3,) to (3,1) I get a (3,3).  That's because the (3,) gets promoted to (1,3) (auto add of a leading dimension):

```
In [48]: Out[41]+np.ones((3,1))
Out[48]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 2., 3.]])
```

But that kind of promotion is not allowed when assigning.

Don't skip too much of the basic `numpy` documentation.  Otherwise details like this will confuse you.

Comment: I took some time to read about broadcasting and how NumPy "reads" from the right to the left looking for matching axes dimensions. I was able to work my example from above into the correct form that it assembled the array as I wanted. This was translated directly to the actual data analysis script also works properly now.